# An $L^2 $ martingale $M_n$ is bounded in $L^2$ if and only if $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} E[M_k-M_{k-1}]^2 < \infty$

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, lp-spaces, martingales

In the following proof

[image]
[image]

These notes assume that bounded in $L^p$ means $\sup_n E[|X|^p]< \infty$

I see clearly the if part:

If $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} E[M_k-M_{k-1}]^2 < \infty$, then $E[M_n^2]<\infty \implies \sup_n E[M_n^2]< \infty$ from the Pythagorean theorem in the second equality of the first line of the proof
**But how do I prove the converse?**

If $\sup_n E[M_n^2]<\infty$, the best I can do is use Holder's inequality:

$E[M_k-M_{k-1}]^2\le E[M_k]^2+E[M_{k-1}]^2+E[M_kM_{k-1}] \le E[M_k]^2+E[M_{k-1}]^2+E[M_k^2]E[M_{k-1}^2] < \infty$

but this doesn't guarantee that the series is finite. **How should I proceed?**

EDIT:

Following the suggestion of geetha290krm:

$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}E(M_k-M_{k-1})^2=\lim_n \sum_{k=1}^nE(M_k-M_{k-1})^2 = \lim_n E[(M_n-M_0)^2]$
$\le \lim_n ( E[M_{n}^2]+ E[M_{0}^2] +  2E[|M_{n}M_{0}|])$
$\le \lim_n ( E[M_{n}^2]+ E[M_{0}^2] +  2E[M_{n}^2][M_{0}^2])$
$\le \lim_n (\sup_r E[M_{r}^2]+\sup_r E[M_{r}^2] + 2\sup_r E[M_{r}^2]\sup_r E[M_{r}^2])= 2K+2K^2 < \infty$,  with $K=\sup_r E[M_{r}^2]$

Comment: In the third line of the proof of Theorem 7.5 just omit the inequality. You will get the conclusion immediately.

Comment: @geetha290krm So you mean this line:  $ \lim \inf_{r}E(M_{n+r}-M_n)^2=\lim \inf_r \sum_{k=n+1}^{n+r} E(M_k-M_{k-1})^2=\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} E(M_k-M_{k-1})^2 $

Comment: I don't know how to conclude anything from that.The liminf and the difference are in the way. Do I still have to use Holder?

Comment: You are just over thinking. The third line in the proof does not have any infimum, liminf etc.  A series $\sum a_n$ of non-negative terms is convergent if its partial sums are bounded.

Comment: @geetha290krm  I think I got it, can you take a look at the Edit?